# UPS on SharePoint 2016 - Trusted Claims Provider or AD LDS

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, adfs, ups, ad-lds

I have got ADFS working fine on a SharePoint 2016 farm. I need to use LDAPCP for the people picker and set the LDAP to point to a domain.

So if I use the 'trusted provider' in UPS will it go to the nearest domain (the domain the Sharepoint server is built on)? Or is there a product out there so I can choose the domain in ADFS for UPS? As the people are in a different domain (that's why I am using ADFS).

Or I have the opportunity to use the LDAP itself (the LDAP itself is an AD LDS server).

Any ideas?